# Other than InputText, is there any component to get user input that does not correspond to a field on a Salesforce object?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would like to have something similar to Picklist, but Picklist needs to bind to sObject.

Other than InputText, is there any component to get user input that does not correspond to a field on a Salesforce object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different VF tags that don't tie directly to a SF object, but rather than controller properties.

```
inputText
inputCheckbox
inputHidden
inputTextArea
selectList
selectOption
selectOptions
selectRadio
selectCheckboxes
```

Check the VF developers guide for info on these

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/

Also, new in the Winter 14 release, they came out with the `<apex:input>` tag.  This tage references a controller property and does not need to tie to a SF object field.

*From the Release notes.*

> is a new, HTML5-friendly, general purpose input component
>   that adapts to the data expected by a form field. It uses the HTML
>   type attribute to allow client browsers to display type-appropriate
>   user input widgets

**More Information**

https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/08/winter-14-developer-preview.html

Comment: Thanks, @SF_Ninja!  This looks like a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for `apex:selectList`.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm

Comment: Thanks, @couchand!  This is really similar to Picklist.  The only problem is that it displays all the options at once, which looks weird in `view` mode.

Comment: You can prevent this by setting the size to 1, then it only shows 1 selectoption at a time, and looks like a traditional picklist

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I want. Thanks, @SF_Ninja!